# Como hacer para que un input solo acepte números con js

Tags: javascript

Lo único que hacía era poner a mi campo esta línea :

```
$(“form#frmAlta input[id    =‘txtIdentificador’]”).attr(“type”, “Number”);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme...

Comment: Busca sobre expresiones regulares

Comment: [Esto puede ayudare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3pC93LgP18)

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema exactamente? Tu código (bien escrito) ya te devuelve un input que sólo acepta números (tanto enteros como decimales): `$("form#frmAlta input[id='txtIdentificador']").attr("type", "Number");`

Comment: No me funciona y me sigue aceptando letras, solo lo quiero para números

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente función para bloquear que el usuario ingrese cualquier carácter que no sea número.

Opción 1.

```js
function numero(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"  id="numero" name="numero" onkeypress="return numero(event)" />
```

El problema de tu código es que funcionará en ciertos navegadores, dado que el atributo number no es estándar

Espero te sirva,
Saludos